# Hypothesis Testing-Statistics

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

> $X_1$ and $X_2$ constitute a random sample of size 2 from a population given by $f(x, T)=T\cdot {x^{T-1}}$ for $0<x<1$ and equal to zero elsewhere. If Critical region is $x_1\cdot x_2\geqslant 3/4$ is used to test the null hypothesis $T=1$ against $T=2$, what is the power of this test at $T=2$?

I defined beta as $\mathbb P\{x_1\cdot x_2<3/4 \mid  T=2\}$ or equivalently $1-\mathbb P\{x_1\cdot x_2>3/4 \mid T=2\}$. I understand the $f(x_1\cdot x_2)= T^2{x_1^{T-1}}{x_2^{T-1}}$. I used this to calculate the required probability but I am not getting the given answer for $1-\beta$ (the given answer is 0.114).

Comment: Show your computation of $P[x_1x_2\lt3/4\mid T=2]$.

Comment: Hi Did..i did the double integral of x1*x2*T^2*X1^(T-1)*X2^(T-1)dxi dx2 and the limits of the integration used were x1 goes from 3/4*x2 to 1 7 X2 goes from 3/4 to 1. I have a felling the limits i used are incorrect